# Using ego function from iGraph to generate a list of connected nodes to parse through a function

Tags: r, node.js, igraph, vertices, sna

I'm having some trouble working with the iGraph package with R. Specifically when i'm trying to get all the nodes within 2 degrees of separation from a given node then use that list to run some operations on via a function.

I'm not super confident with how lists in R work, let alone iGraph.vs classes either.

Ideally I would want to generate a list of the vertices using the `ego` to the second degree `Listnode_test <- (ego(Graph1, 2, "accumsan"))`. This returns `Listnode_test`. Here's the output:

`structure(list(structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 24L,
1 c(1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 16, 24, 32, 59, 64, 2, 4, 6, 14, 15, 1`

The problem is that I want it to return a list of the nodes ideally in just a list that says `"node1, node2, node3"` etc.. so that I can run them through a function like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(Listnode_test[[1]]))
{
  Perspective <- 1
  Listnode <- neighborhood.size(Graph1, 1, Listnode_test[[1]][i], mode="in")
  ##a save script either to a DF or global env
}
```

Basically I want to get a node, then get a list of every node that's connected to it within X degree's of separation. After I've generated this list I want to feed it into the function which calculates the in-degree for each node in the list provided.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've provided an example of the vertices DF below:

`> vertices
                           from                 to       query
1                      accumsan                  a     Benefit
2                       nonummy                  a     Benefit
3                        mollis                  a     Benefit
4                         velit                  a     Benefit
5                            et                  a     Benefit
6                     vulputate                  a     Benefit
7                         magna                  a     Benefit
8                            et                  a        Risk
9                       feugiat                 ac     Benefit
10                      feugiat                 ac Sequential 
11                       mollis           accumsan     Benefit
12                            a           accumsan     Benefit
13                       mauris           accumsan     Benefit
14                           et           accumsan     Benefit
15                    fermentum           accumsan       Other
16                       mollis           accumsan       Scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I've figured out how to do it now.

```
    node.list <- Listnode_test[[1]][i]
    > node.list
    + 1/68 vertex, named:
    [1] vel

    node.list <- as_ids(node.list)

    > as_ids(node.list)
    [1] "vel"


> node.list <- as_ids(node.list)
> df <- data.frame (node.list, in.degree, perspective)
> df
  node.list in.degree perspective
1       vel         2           1
```

The `as_ids()` function in iGraph converts an iGraph.vs into a vector :)

Comment: If  this is the correct answer, please accept it.  You can accept your own answers.